# Meteor client side function then server side response

Tags: java, json, sockets, meteor

A have a simple java app using the Apache HTTP libraries to communicate with a Meteor app. I am a bit of a Meteor newb so forgive me if this is simple but here goes - The idea is the java app will send a post request to log in, then send a second post request to generate a string, and if the user is logged in the string is returned via JSON, if not return "false" or something. However client-side you cannot return JSON, and server-side you obviously cannot check if your logged in. how can i check if a person is logged in but still return a raw JSON string?? Are there any other better ways of communicating with Java??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this (which includes authentication) is to use a restapi, such as the one called restivus. https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus

It will allow your java app to authenticate and then request data, in a very standard restapi, which is easy for you to construct. The site has examples to help illustrate